# How do I get the highest `field_id` value that exists in content of a specific type?

Tags: 7, hooks

I have a content type which, among other things, have a field which contains a unique ID number (this number is used to connect the individual content to related information stored on paper).

When creating new entries I'd like to automatically generate this ID by finding the highest ID already present in the system, and calculating the next ID from that.

I have written a small module (using `hook_menu()`) which presents the user an interface for adding new content. How can I, from within this module, get the  `field_id` values of my already existing content? (So that I can calculate which ID a new entry should have?)

Is there any PHP command which can be made to return an array containing all the `field_id`s from my content type?

---

Worth to know here is that the system is kinda small (500–1000 entries of my content type, at most). There will also only be a single person entering data at a time. Also, I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest sulotion I can think about is to use [Computed field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field) module and the id field will be computed field.
Then,  in the field read the last value using `variable_get()` and then update that value using `variable_set()`.

Comment: Your answer led me in the right direction. – I ended up using `variable_get()` to set a `#default_value` in the render array for my form. (Though there was no need for the Computed field module.)

Comment: Great! You are right there is no need in computed field :)